# Authentication or Session Timeout on GoDaddy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I build my application on Asp.net core 6 here is my program.cs file code

```
using Portal._keenthemes.libs;
using Portal._keenthemes;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Portal.Data;
using PortalServices.Context;
using PortalServices.Models;
using PortalServices.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using System.Globalization;
using Portal.Security;
using PortalServices.Services;
using Portal.Data.Data;
using PortalServices.Models.Email;
using Portal.GlobalValues;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>(
    options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true
) 
       .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddTokenProvider<EmailConfirmationTokenProvider<User>>("email_confirmation_provider");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<PortalContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
    options.SlidingExpiration = false;
});

builder.Services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(o => o.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromHours(7));


builder.Services.AddScoped<IKTTheme, KTTheme>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IKTBootstrapBase, KTBootstrapBase>();

builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddViewLocalization(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-NZ");
    options.SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("en-NZ") };
    options.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>();
});

builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;

    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false; 

    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
});

builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(15);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy =>
    {
        policy.AddRequirements(new AdminRole());
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    });
});

IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();


builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
builder.Services.Configure<SmtpSettings>(configuration.GetSection("SmtpSettings"));

builder.Services.AddScoped<IPortalContext, PortalContext>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICategoriesService, CategoriesService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IProductService, ProductService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEmailService, EmailService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IJobService, JobService>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<ScheduledService>();



var app = builder.Build();

KTThemeSettings.init(configuration);

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseSession();
app.UseRequestLocalization();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseThemeMiddleware();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "Identity",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Identity}/{action=Logout}");

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "Admin",
        pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}",
        defaults: new { area = "Admin" }
    );

    endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
    {
        if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var userManager = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>();
            var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(context.User);

            if(user == null)
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/Account/Login");
            }
            else if (await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Admin"))
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/Admin");
                return;
            } else if (await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Seller"))
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/Seller");
                return;
            } else if (await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Freelancer"))
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/Freelancer");
                return;
            }
        }

        context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Index");
    });
});

app.MapRazorPages();


using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    await DbSeeder.SeedRoleAndAdminAsync(scope.ServiceProvider);
}

app.Run();


public class EmailConfirmationTokenProvider<TUser> : DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser> where TUser : class
{
    public EmailConfirmationTokenProvider(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider,
        IOptions<EmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions> options, ILogger<EmailConfirmationTokenProvider<TUser>> logger)
        : base(dataProtectionProvider, options, logger)
    {
    }
}

public class EmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions : DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions
{ }
```

The application is functioning flawlessly in the local environment; however, an issue arises when it is deployed on GoDaddy's server environment. Specifically, the problem occurs when an unauthorized user attempts to access certain features within the application. Despite extensive efforts, I have been unable to pinpoint the root cause of this issue and have not received the necessary support to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing ISS poll from Classic to Integrated and Provided expire item works for me